# Mysql identify which table a row came from in double LEFT OUTTER JOIN with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

My below query works, but there are two things I  want to get from the query that I don't know how to do.

1. How to tell which `LEFT JOIN` the final returned row is coming from?
2. Is it possible to also return the total count from each `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT ch.user_ID, ch.clID FROM clubHistory AS ch 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN clubRaffleWinners AS cr ON 
     ch.user_ID = cr.user_ID  
     AND cr.cID=1157 
     AND cr.rafID=18  
     AND cr.chDate1 = '2022-06-04' 
   WHERE  ch.cID=1157  
     AND ch.crID=1001   
     AND ch.ceID=1167  
     AND ch.chDate = '2022-06-04' 
     AND cr.user_ID IS NULL 
   GROUP BY ch.user_ID ) 
UNION ALL 
  (SELECT cu.user_ID, cu.clID FROM clubUsers AS cu 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clubRaffleWinners AS cr1 ON 
      cu.user_ID = cr1.user_ID  
      AND cr1.cID=1157 
      AND cr1.rafID=18  
      AND cr1.chDate1 = '2022-06-04' 
    WHERE  cu.cID=1157  
      AND cu.crID=1001   
      AND cu.ceID=1167  
      AND cu.calDate = '2022-06-04' 
      AND cr1.user_ID IS NULL 
    GROUP BY cu.user_ID )
) as winner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ;
```

In my two left join select statements I tried:

```
  (SELECT ch.user_ID as chUserID, ch.clID FROM clubHistory AS ch 
   and
  (SELECT cu.user_ID as cuUserID, cu.clID FROM clubUsers AS cu
```

But every single result, after dozens and dozens of tries comes back a `user_ID` or `chUserID`.  When I remove the `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` - the only two columns that come back are `user_ID, clID` or `chUserID, clID` even though the combined results is the full list of both tables.  Is this even possible?

And #2 above, is it possible to extract the total counts from each `LEFT JOIN` with and with out the final `order by rand() limit 1` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 add an extra column containing a value that identifies which subquery of the `UNION` it is.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT 'history' AS which, ch.user_ID, ch.clID FROM clubHistory AS ch 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN clubRaffleWinners AS cr ON 
     ch.user_ID = cr.user_ID  
     AND cr.cID=1157 
     AND cr.rafID=18  
     AND cr.chDate1 = '2022-06-04' 
   WHERE  ch.cID=1157  
     AND ch.crID=1001   
     AND ch.ceID=1167  
     AND ch.chDate = '2022-06-04' 
     AND cr.user_ID IS NULL 
   GROUP BY ch.user_ID ) 
UNION ALL 
  (SELECT 'users' AS which, cu.user_ID, cu.clID FROM clubUsers AS cu 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clubRaffleWinners AS cr1 ON 
      cu.user_ID = cr1.user_ID  
      AND cr1.cID=1157 
      AND cr1.rafID=18  
      AND cr1.chDate1 = '2022-06-04' 
    WHERE  cu.cID=1157  
      AND cu.crID=1001   
      AND cu.ceID=1167  
      AND cu.calDate = '2022-06-04' 
      AND cr1.user_ID IS NULL 
    GROUP BY cu.user_ID )
) as winner ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ;
```

Please only ask one question at a time.